# PHP password validator output

Tags: php

I know there are several threads involving this subject already but my questions is more about the output. I have an array with 10 passwords. They are sent to a function to validate the password. Right now, the function is (somewhat) doing what I need it to, i.e. catching passwords that don't meet the criteria, but it is only catching one thing at a time. I need the function to return EACH criteria that the password did not meet. So for example: "abcd" should return a string stating that "Password is too short, Password did not contain a number, Password did not contain a special character, etc."

How do I add to the string each time an if statement is not met? Thanks so much for any help!

```
function validatePassword($pwd) {
     if (strlen($pwd) < '8') {
        $invalidPassword = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
    }
    elseif(strlen($pwd) > '16') {
        $invalidPassword = "Your Password is too long!";
    }   
    elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$pwd)) {
        $invalidPassword = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
    }
    elseif(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$pwd)) {
        $invalidPassword = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
    }
    elseif(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$pwd)) {
        $invalidPassword = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
    }

    return $invalidPassword;
}

$Passwords = array("donkeypass", "password", "Prebyt1na!", "1234", "abcd", "narW1@asndk", "pasS w0rd!", "maK%sh1ft", "mypasswordisthebestpasswordever!23493484023", "sD123#vAr2@y7");
foreach ($Passwords as $value) {
    echo validatePassword($value);
}
```

Comment: Simple: Don't put it in an elseif. Build an array and append messages for each failed test, then iterate over the array when returning this to the user.

Comment: Sorry I am new at php and programming in general. Do you mean use just `if` statements instead of `elseif`?

Comment: Sure. Something like this: https://3v4l.org/0t3Ad

Comment: Sidenote: Please don't restrict people to 16 character passwords. Ideally, you should accept passwords of any size. If you want a sane upper limit, make it at least 100.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski that looks really nice! I have one more question, how would I get the password that is being tested to show up as well? For example the first password it checks is `donkeypass`, how would I get my ouput to say something like `"Password tested: "donkeypass. Errors: ...."`?

Comment: I second @ScottArciszewski's comment about password length. There is little to no justification to impose a max length limit. If the password is hashed (which it should be!) the stored password length will always be the same regardless of what the actual password is.

Answer (score 3):

In order to keep a list of the failures, we must first turn all the elseif's to if's. Then we are going to collect the errors in an array. When using the [] operator this just means add this to the end of the current array.

Then we will return those results. If the size (count()) is > 0 we will use implode to concatenate the error array into a string separated by commas and output the result.

If no errors are found, we will output a positive result.

```
   function validatePassword($pwd)
    {
        $invalidPassword = array();
        if (strlen($pwd) < '8') {
            $invalidPassword[] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
        }
        if (strlen($pwd) > '16') {
            $invalidPassword[] = "Your Password is too long!";
        }
        if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd)) {
            $invalidPassword[] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
        }
        if (!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pwd)) {
            $invalidPassword[] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
        }
        if (!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pwd)) {
            $invalidPassword[] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
        }

        return $invalidPassword;
    }

    $Passwords = array("donkeypass", "password", "Prebyt1na!", "1234", "abcd", "narW1@asndk", "pasS w0rd!", "maK%sh1ft", "mypasswordisthebestpasswordever!23493484023", "sD123#vAr2@y7");
    foreach ($Passwords as $value) {
        $return = validatePassword($value);
        if (count($return) > 0) {
            echo "Password Strong Test(s) failed $value " . implode(",", $return) . "<br/>";
        }else{
            echo "Password Strong Test(s) passed $value <br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I get the output in a table format to do something like: 
`Password Strong Test(s) failed
donkeypass no no upper case, no special character, length`

Comment: I've revised your code and given the above as an example. I would recommend reading the PHP documents on any method used you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote function for you:

```
function validatePassword($pwd) {
     $messages = array();
     $index = 0;
     if (strlen($pwd) < '8') {
        $messages[$index] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
        $index++;
    }
    if(strlen($pwd) > '16') {
        $messages[$index] = "Your Password is too long!";
        $index++;
    }   
    if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$pwd)) {
        $messages[$index] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
        $index++;
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$pwd)) {
        $messages[$index] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
        $index++;
    }
    if(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$pwd)) {
        $messages[$index] = "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
        $index++;
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

Comment: Using that, I get the output of `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`???

Comment: Do an `implode($messages, ' ')`

Comment: @Firedrake969 You got the arguments in the wrong order

Comment: Oh, oops.  Didn't look up the function, and it's been a few months since I've worked with PHP.